# Laravel 5.8 callback API

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Am developing a web application using laravel 5.8 and am stuck before final step.

The full scenario is:
Because am trying mobile money payment service aggregation with a thirdy party company, when i use ajax to send a request with phone number and amount to `/requestpayment` API they gave me, i get a **"pending"** JSON response in chrome console which means it works fine.

But they say i have to give them a **callback URL** to be able to receive the JSON response in my laravel app so that i can for example save a payment record into DB.

---

Now, the documentation says this regarding responses:
xyz acts as a client and Invokes the App by sending it the status of the
pending transaction via an HTTP post. Which can either be successfull or failed. Partners are
required to provide an **end point url (Callback URL)** to which the xyz gateway will submit the request.
Below is an example in Python programming language:

```
data = {
'requesttransactionid':''4522233',
'transactionid':'6004994884',
'responsecode' :'01',
'status':'Successfull',
'statusdesc':'Successfully Processed Transaction',
'referenceno':'312333883'
 }
```

r = requests.post(url, json={'jsonpayload':data},headers={'contenttype':"application/json"},verify=False)

---

So, My question is: How am i going to capture above JSON in my laravel 5.8 app to get that `'responsecode'` and `'status'`??

Am i going to create an API posting to a controller and then what? Help please!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new route in your application to accept this data from your Remote API.

```
 Route::post('/endpoint', function (Request $request) {
    dd($request->all());
    /*
    [
        'requesttransactionid' => '4522233',
        'transactionid' => '6004994884',
        'responsecode' => '01',
        'status' => 'Successfull',
        'statusdesc' => 'Successfully Processed Transaction',
        'referenceno' => '312333883'
    ]
    */
});
```

Don't forget to add the POST exception in your **VerifyCsrfToken** Middleware

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '/endpoint',
    ];
}
```

Once this is done provide the URL of the route to your Provider:
`https://myapp.com/endpoint`

Comment: Sorry for this question but how will i know that this POST myapp.com/endpoint has received a request? Am sending request using AJAX

Comment: you have to put your logic instead of the `dd($request->all());` You could, for example, save the successful payment record in the database